# How to efficiently load live results from multiple data sources

Tags: php, mysql, xml, caching

I'm building a price comparison website (using PHP & MySQL) whose live search results are sourced from xml data feeds supplied by partner sites. Potentially, there could be 20+ feeds called per search request.

Currently, a site visitor selects their search options, then a PHP script requests the xml data (based on the given search options) from the partner sites, formats the results and sends them straight to the browser.

The system is working well in testing with one user, but my concern is that over time more visitors will slow the site down considerably due to the live nature of the data sources.

I've calculated that the actual data should only need to be refreshed no more than once every 10 minutes.

Can anyone recommend a caching technique using PHP and MySQL, or just some way to make this system more efficient? Perhaps every 10 minutes I should run a script that stores the results of the most common searches in a MySQL summary table?

Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should be looking into a Javascript framework to parse the xml data instead?  Transfer the load from the server to the client.

Comment: I agree with @Devon, this might be best suited for JavaScript. Are the 20+ feeds constant? Or are there thousands of feeds are you're only requesting 20+ of them?

Comment: The feeds are constant for now but more feeds would be added over time, say 1 per year max. Once the search options are submitted the PHP scripts first query my MySQL database for initial records filtering, then the script requests the necessary live data for those matched records only. I suppose I could create a JS set of objects for formatting the data using the same logic as the PHP formatting scripts in the backend.